# aes ctr 128 bit decryption in Embedded system

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, embedded, aes

As part of DFU(Device Firmware Upgrade) we need to decrypt the binary which comes from PC. The Decryption algorithm shall be AES CTR 128 bit decryption. Since chip(TI DM3732) doesn't support h/w decryption need to implement s/w decryption. I see there are many libraries available for invoking "AES_encrypt" API, but i'm not able to integrate it to my codebase. Can anyone please help me how to proceed?

Comment: What libraries did you try to use?

Comment: I found one lib from OpenSSL-Win32 called "libeay32.a". I tried to include this lib into my build system and called "AES_encrypt" from .c file. But ended up with Linking error.

Comment: We can't reproduce the error since you didn't tell what the error is. " i'm not able to" is not an error description.

Comment: Error which i got is "undefined reference to `AES_encryptt'". I just wanted to know that how can i call "AES_encrypt" API from .c file? Our Embedded system runs with Nucleus RTOS, Is there any dependency?

Comment: Why is the binary encrypted, doesn't it just need authentication?

Comment: Did you build the library yourself? What you described sounds like you just took library compiled for some other platform and you try to link it with code that should be compiled for DM3732.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>**Note:** Posted as an answer because it's too long to post as a comment.</sup>

---

Without wishing to sound too negative, I think the best answer is that if you can't integrate a reliable crypto library into your codebase, then you'll just have to find someone who can.

Here's why: Decent cryptography software isn't easy to write. If you trawl through SO and other sites, you'll probably find code that does what you want. **However**, unless this software has been thoroughly peer-reviewed and stress-tested, it will most likely be vulnerable to all sorts of [side-channel attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack). It may even have bugs that will cause it to operate incorrectly under certain circumstances.

We seem to be advancing into an era when even ordinary objects like [kettles](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2465342/blackberry-hacks-a-kettle-to-demonstrate-iot-security-strain) and even [toilets](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-23575249) can connect to the internet. And because manufacturers have been cutting corners when it comes to security, these devices are easy to commandeer. As a result, we are starting to see massive [botnet attacks](http://www.zdnet.com/article/blame-the-internet-of-things-for-causing-massive-web-outage/) originating from "smart" home devices.

Bruce Schneier spelt out the dangers in a [speech to the House of Representatives’ Energy & Commerce Committee](http://www.dailydot.com/layer8/bruce-schneier-internet-of-things/) just last week:

> *Everything is now a computer: This is not a phone. It’s a computer that makes phone calls. A refrigerator is a computer that keeps things cold. An ATM machine is a computer with money inside. Your car is not a mechanical device with a computer. It’s a computer with four wheels and an engine… And this is the Internet of Things, and this is what caused the DDoS attack we’re talking about.*